# Angular Bootstrap Progressbar Cannot assign type dynamically

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, nested, interpolation

I am using the angular bootstrap progress bar, and want to insert a progress bar for each inserted file.

Interpolation symbols are set to '{[{' and '}]}'.

```
    {% set barName = "formatFileName( item.file.name )" %}
    {% set typeName = "'progressType_" ~  form.vars.name ~ "_' + " ~ barName %}
    {% set readyValue = "{[{" ~ typeName ~ "}]}" %}

    <uib-progressbar
                class="progress-striped active"
                value="item.progress"
                type="{{ readyValue }}"
    >
        {[{ item.progress }]}%
    </uib-progressbar>
```

Not only that, but I would like to be able to change the color of each bar separately depending on whether the
 upload failed or succeeded, so in my controller, I do the following upon upload success(assume $scope.elementName is set):

```
    $scope.uploader.onSuccessItem = function(item, response, status, headers) {

        angular.forEach(response, function(elem, key) {
            var ind = $scope.formatFileName(key);
            if (typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem.length > 0) {

                $scope['progressType_' + $scope.elementName + '_' + ind] = "danger";

                angular.forEach(elem, function(error) {
                    $scope.uploadErrors[item.file.name].push(error);
                });

            } else {
                $scope['progressType_' + $scope.elementName + '_' + ind]  = "success";
                $scope.formData[$scope.elementName].push(key);
            }
        });
    };
```

The problem arises where, in twig, resulting string, i.e.:

```
"{[{'progressType_formName_' + formatFileName( item.file.name )}]}"
```

is interpolated to

```
"progressType_formName_fileName"
```

While, what I relly need is

```
"{[{progressType_formName_fileName}]}"
```

so that I can assign a value to this from the controller.

I know that there can be no nested interpolation and that it cannot work like that anyway. So if anyone knows of another way to achieve this, any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: mmm looks like a bit of a hodge podge of technologies - i would be doing all this kinda stuff ... {% set barName = "formatFileName( item.file.name )" %} ... in my angular controller ... anyway - can't you just escape the characters in twig? (never head of twig before)

Comment: Hi Danday74, Yes, If I could get the item.file.name in angular this could help, I'll check that out.

Answer (score -1):

Used Angular UI bootstrap -> Progressbar (ui.bootstrap.progressbar)

With this I do all my progress bar dinamic :) more info [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: That is the progress bar I am using... :)